# Azure Application Insights in a desktop client app without internet access

Tags: c#, .net, azure, winforms, azure-application-insights

We're thinking about adding Application Insights into our WinForms Desktop client application which runs on hardware without internet access.

The server application to which the desktop application connects to has internet access.

Is it possible to send the AI data from the clients to our local server and then to azure?

Comment: But your client has no Internet

Comment: But has lan access to a server application which has internet access. So instead of directly sending AI data from the client to azure I want to send it from my client app to my server (app) and from the server to azure.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to use [Telemetry Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c). Your telemetry processor will be invoked for every telemetry item. `Process` function can implement sending it to wherever you'd like. By not calling `this.Next.Process(item)` you will prevent this item to be processed by the rest of a chain (and as a result will not be sent anywhere).

Potential other option - emulate Application Insights endpoint. The challenge here is that it might be incompatible with further versions.

Another option is to implement your own ITelemetryChannel and ITelemetrySink.